# Bootstrap as button fa-icon inside input or text area

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add the fa-icon as a button inside the input as you guys can see:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group">
    <textarea class="form-control custom-control" rows="2" style="border-radius: 3rem;"></textarea> 
<span class=""> <i class="fa fa-comments fa-2x" style="padding-top: 5px; color: #18d26e;"></i></span>

<!-- or -->
 <input class="form-control custom-control" rows="2" style="border-radius: 3rem;"></input>   
  <span class=""> <i class="fa fa-comments fa-2x" style="padding-top: 5px; color: #18d26e;"></i></span>
   
 
</div>
```

The question is how to add it as a button inside the input and also have other buttons inside same input? I would like to add and have functionality to also add more then 1 button inside, like left button , right button etc.

I also tried and added this example on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s7zLf0e1/

Comment: You're not able to add buttons inside input fields. What I think you're trying to do is get a button to sit on top of an input field. For this, you would need to use some CSS to move the position of the buttons. Try having your inputs in a form, then set the z-index of the buttons greater than the input's z-index. Be careful that the text inside the input doesn't go under the buttons though.

Comment: could you answer with a example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't place buttons within inputs. I would recommend that you style a div or form to look like the input field like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/mattclarke/wghr6xtn/3/

Markup:

```
<form class="m-5 border inline-block pr-3">
  <input type="text" class="p-2" placeholder="Place text in here...">
  <button class="bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-full px-1">
    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```

> You will need to change the CSS to fit in with your site.

This keeps the desired effect of a button within the input, although it is not.

Comment: it do not work it's only the html markup, could you give a complete example with css?

Comment: @Developer I have updated the answers link with a CSS-only version. You will need to take that and change it for your website.

Comment: sorry it also do not work with bootstrap style please take my code as example , your code conflits with bootstrap style so it do not work on bootstrap

Comment: @Developer Yeah, you will need to make custom css rules to support this style you want to use. Bootstrap does not offer what I've offered, you need to write a custom version in order to achieve what I have posted. The only thing close in Bootstrap would be: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#inline-forms - You can see the username example.

Comment: yeah this is what I did but it do not work when I add `style="border-radius: 3rem;` to the inputs.  I need a circular style

Comment: You can't do this using Bootstrap. You need to make your own classes fit within your design. I have provided a skeleton of what you need to do, you now need to interpret that into your design.